# Is it possible to use collectionGroup from a reference in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to use `collectionGroup` to query on collections from a specific collection. Here's an example:

I have two collections (at the root) "a" and "b".
Both "a" and "b" collections hold documents.
Each document has a collection labeled "x".

Now if I use `collectionGroup('x')` it will group all collection labeled "x" in the database (in both "a" and "b").
What I want is to group all "x" from collection "a".

I couldn't find an answer in the documentation, maybe it's not possible?
If it's not possible, what would be the easiest and efficient workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. A collection group query always refers to all collections of the same name and cannot be limited in the collections it will use to match documents.

You could instead store some field in all of the subcollection "x" documents that tells you which "a" or "b" top-level collection they belong to, and use that field in a filter on the collection group query.

Comment: Indeed! I'll go with that solution because I'm still at the specification phase. Let's imagine I had an existing database already, I guess would have had no choice but to query all documents in "a" and do the final query on each document ref, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you could have simply queried the subcollection under a directly if that's all you wanted.